# How do you create an EntityManager when you are unsure of the unit name?

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee, jpa-2.0, java-ee-6

I'm in a situation where I need to determine the EntityManager's unit name at run time.

For example, I'd like to do something like this:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = findAppropriateJdbcName())
EntityManager entityManager;
```

However, this is not possible with annotations.

Is it possible to create the EntityManager when your not sure of what the unit name is until run time?

Answer (score 7):

It is possible to specify the persistence unit (PU) name at runtime, but this is a parameter used in the creation of the `EntityManagerFactory`, not an individual `EntityManager`. See the [Javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Persistence.html) for the `Persistence` class method `createEntityManagerFactory()`. Example:

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(unitname);
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
// ...
```

I do this in a non-Java EE application (using Java 6 SE calls in a Tomcat-hosted web app) but I'm not sure how you do the same thing in a container-managed Java EE 6 application. It is possible.

Answer (score 3):

Here you have to manually create entityManager without using annotations through JNDI to point it to different persistent unit at runtime.

```
public EntityManager initializeEM(String pUnitName){

Context iCtx = new InitialContext();
String lookUpString = "java:comp/env/persistence/"+pUnitName;
javax.persistence.EntityManager entityManager =
                (javax.persistence.EntityManager)iCtx.lookup(lookUpString);

return entityManager;
}
```