# Inject EntityManagerFactory in a servlet dispatcher (non managed)

Tags: java, spring, jpa, ejb, entitymanager

I want to create a servlet dispatcher capable of doing some JPA operations. This servlet must not have any dependencies on Spring or EJB. So, my intention is to inject EntityManagerFactory to it programatically. Then, the dispatcher must handle transactions and create/open/close EntityManager when required.

So I did this code in a sample application, using Spring 3 and EclipseLink:

```
public class Initializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext context) {

        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext appContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        appContext.scan(...);
        appContext.refresh();

        EntityManagerFactory emf = appContext.getBean(EntityManagerFactory.class);
        MyDispatcher dispatcher = new MyDispatcher(emf);
        context.addServlet("my", dispatcher).addMapping("/my/*");
    }
}



public class MyDispatcher extends HttpServlet {
    ...

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        emf.createEntityManager();
        // java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempting to execute an operation on a closed EntityManagerFactory.
    }
}
```

The problem is when this dispatcher needs to create an EntityManager an IllegalStateExceptionis thrown. Debugging I have seen that EntityManagerFactoryImpl.close() is called automatically after all beans are instantiated.

What am I doing wrong? Is there some way of achieving what I need?

Thanks.

Comment: Can refer http://stackoverflow.com/q/4292969/366964

Comment: What does appContext.getBean(EntityManagerFactory.class) actually do?  How is it obtaining the EMF instance?

Comment: @NayanWadekar: My persistence unit is defined exclusively with Spring, without persistence.xml. So, JNDI throws a NameNotFoundException: Name persistence is not bound in this Context. Persistence static method looks for persistence.xml files, obviously with no success.

Comment: @bkail: In Spring I define a LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean, which must return an instance of EMF when I call appContext.getBean(EntityManagerFactory.class). This works, but the problem is that this EMF is automatically closed by Spring.

Comment: I am not familiar with spring, this link might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/q/1132565/366964